# How do I convert a string to an new object's name?

Tags: java, object, constructor, multiple-constructors

I'd like to write a program which creates a set of objects in a loop....

(i.e.)

```
String newFirm = "empty";

for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
          newFirm = "firm" + i;
          firm newFirm = new firm();
    }
```

and then of course I would need something like

```
 stringToObject = "firm" + x;
 stringToObject.type = "service";
 stringToObject.size = 10000;
```

Obviously this code is fictional, but It expresses how I'd ideally create and call for objects. The nature of this program is such that the final number of firms (or other objects) are not known at the time of compiling.

Is there a method by which I can convert a given string into the name of an object (either to call or to create) as well as creating objects "on the fly"?

Comment: Are you talking about objects or classes?

Comment: You're looking for collections.

Comment: @bevynQ objects of a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Firm> myList = new ArrayList<Firm>();
```

And in your loop,

```
Firm firm = new Firm();
firm.type = "service";
myList.add(firm);
```

And to get it,

```
Firm f = myList.get(index);
```

Comment: Perfect!! thanks! to anyone else with the same question [here's a link with more info on arraylist that helped me.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8NMfy90sP4)

Answer (score 1):

> convert a given string into the name of an object

Your need is to refer an object with the string in your hand. I'll suggest `Hashmap<String,Object>`

Eg:- you have a String,

```
String name="object_name";
```

And your class is `Firm`. Now,

```
Hashmap<String,Firm> objs=new Hashmap<String,Firm>();// note:your for loop comes after this line
Firm new_firm=new Firm();
new_firm.type = "service";
new_firm.size = 10000;
objs.put(name,new_firm);
```

Now you can refer your object with the string in your hand as

```
objs.get("object_name");
```